# list of unique elements formed by concatenating permutations of the initial lists

Tags: python, list, concatenation, permutation

I would like to combine several lists, each lists should be preserved up to a permutation.

Here is an example:

I would like to combine these lists

```
[[0, 7], [2, 4], [0, 1, 7], [0, 1, 4, 7]]
```

The output I would like to obtain is e.g. this list

```
 [2, 4, 0, 7, 1]
```

Or as Sembei Norimaki phrased the task:

> the result must be a list of unique elements formed by concatenating permutations of the initial lists.

The solution is not unique, and it could be that there is not always a solution possible

Comment: Why is the output not `[0, 7, 2, 4, 1]` here?

Comment: Since the list [0,1,7] has been in the input, so it should be in the output up to a permutation, but the output is like [0,7,....,1]. Thus the 1 has to be next to the 0 and the 7. Is this clear?

Comment: oh, I see, it's `{2, 4}`, `{4, 0, 1, 7}`, `{0, 7}`, `{0, 1, 7}` with the overlaps removed. This smells like graph theory or set theory from beyond my grasp :)

Comment: Would `[0, 1, 7, 4, 2]` be a valid answer? It's `[0,1,7]` plus permutation of `[0,1,4,7]`, plus permutation of `[2,4]`.

Comment: No because the permutation of [0,7] is missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Third time lucky. This is a bit cheesy - it checks every permutation of the source list elements to see which ones are valid:

```py
from itertools import permutations


def check_sublist(sublist, candidate):
    # a permutation of sublist must exist within the candidate list
    sublist = set(sublist)
    # check each len(sublist) portion of candidate
    for i in range(1 + len(candidate) - len(sublist)):
        if sublist == set(candidate[i : i + len(sublist)]):
            return True
    return False


def check_list(input_list, candidate):
    for sublist in input_list:
        if not check_sublist(sublist, candidate):
            return False
    return True


def find_candidate(input_list):
    # flatten input_list and make set of unique values
    values = {x for sublist in input_list for x in sublist}
    for per in permutations(values):
        if check_list(input_list, per):
            print(per)


find_candidate([[0, 7], [2, 4], [0, 1, 7], [0, 1, 4, 7]])
# (0, 7, 1, 4, 2)
# (1, 0, 7, 4, 2)
# (1, 7, 0, 4, 2)
# (2, 4, 0, 7, 1)
# (2, 4, 1, 0, 7)
# (2, 4, 1, 7, 0)
# (2, 4, 7, 0, 1)
# (7, 0, 1, 4, 2)
```

You'd definitely do better applying a knowledge of graph theory and using a graphing library, but that's beyond my wheelhouse at present!

Comment: Thats really helpful! Thank you! I will use this to check if my idea is in general working. If so, I will try to improve it. Thats crazy, that there is no "simple rule" to get this - ok maybe there is, but it is definitely not obvious

Comment: Yep, at least you can reuse `check_list` in the search for something better than `O(N!)` performance :)

Comment: I think I can translate the problem on the problem finding the maximum weighted hamiltonian path, and as far as I know, this is an np complete problem (wikipedia said its FNP, whatever that is:) ).